# Export CSV file have many empty rows

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, csv, cakephp-1.3

I am making the app by CakePHP 1.3 with MSSQL Server 2012. I successfully made the export CSV file from database.

At the first time, I made it having no problems. I continue to make some other function in my app. And than I try to test export function again.

And the problem occurred. The problem is in my CSV file, it has a lot empty rows appeared. I checked in my database, it has no null values and in my controller and export.ctp too.

I don't know why the problem was happened so can someone realize my false?

**My Controller:**

```
function csv_export() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout','Export Words List');
    Configure::write('debug',0);
    $this->layout=false;
    $filename = 'Wordlist_'.date('YmdHis');
    $th=array('id','avoidance_word','avoidance_word_yomi','replace_word','replace_word_yomi','creator','create_time','updator','update_time','invalid_flg');
    $Th_name=array('ID','Avoidance Words','Avoidance Words Yomi','Replace Word','Replace Word Yomi','Creator','Create Time','Updator','Update Time','Invalid Flag');
    $td=$this->MAvoidanceWord->find('all', array('fields'=>$th));
    $this->set(compact('filename','Th_name','td'));
}
```

**My View:**

```
<?php
$csv->addRow($Th_name);
foreach ($td as $t){
    $csv->addRow();
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['id']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['avoidance_word']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['avoidance_word_yomi']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['replace_word']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['replace_word_yomi']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['creator']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['create_time']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['updator']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['update_time']);
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['invalid_flg']);
    $csv->endRow();}
    $csv->setFilename($filename);
    echo $csv->render(true,'UTF-8');
?>
```

**And my CSV file:**

[image]

Update: My CSV file open with Notepad++

[image]

Comment: When you open the CSV file with Notepad++ or other text editors, what do you see?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath it's same

Comment: Did you try my answer? I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove `addRow` from inside the foreach:

```
foreach ($td as $t){
    // $csv->addRow();
    $csv->addField($t['MAvoidanceWord']['id']); 
    ...
```

You can either use `addRow(array)` or `addField` (several times) and endRow
`The fact that you have`addRow` right now means it is adding a blank line several times.

**Second way**: Try adding `ob_clean();` before `$csv->addRow($Th_name);`

Comment: @comelb: I did it but nothing change. Empty rows still was inserted @@

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try ob_clean() too. There seems to be some output from other files

Answer (score 0):

May be issue is not in this code.
Check twice, that you have not any linefeeds echoing anywhere.
May be anything like:

```
  <?php
     //php code
    ?>
    ↓
    ↓
    ↓
```

All content outside your `<?php ?>` block is silent equivalent of echo "...";
So, these linefeeds are printed like echo "\n\n\n\n";

Good practice is to remove last `?>` at all